# get mysql error text from sqlstate error code

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am working on error handling of mysql queries that are written in a different page (let's say page A) than the page responsible of printing them (page B), 
for example:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found
```

I want to get the error message text:

```
Base table or view not found
```

from the code:

```
42S02
```

idealy I am looking for a function like this:

```
get_sqlstate_error_text(42S02)
```

for info, I can't access the last query and I only have the error code

Comment: Are you using pdo or mysqli to run queries ?

Comment: I am using pdo.

Comment: I don't think it can be done in a general basis since a single numeric code can potentially correspond to many different messages, plus it wouldn't be as useful as real messages,which often contain the name of the affected object. I think this needs some clarification: what prevents you from accessing the message? Are you using a third-party library that hides it?

Comment: I am having the queries on many pages (X, Y, Z), when an sql error occurs on one of these pages I want to redirect the user to page A where he can see the error message, Ideally, I would send a GET parameter to page A, for example: pageA.php?error=42502, and then print the error there in a secure way. I am not allowed to use POST, Sessions, Database nor files.

Comment: Funny requirements. SQLSTATE is a technical error code: if user is proficient in SQL he'll miss the real info (`Column '%s' in %s is ambiguous ` is not as good); if not, we'll find the error meaningless anyway. Would hard-coding values in an array count as "file"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how stuff happens:

1. PHP submits a query to MySQL
2. Something breaks, MySQL gets an [internal error code](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-messages-server.html), e.g. `1146`
3. MySQL populates the message template: `Table '%s.%s' doesn't exist` → `Table 'shop.customers' doesn't exist`
4. MySQL gets the mapped standard [SQLSTATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLSTATE) that corresponds to the internal code: `42S02`
5. Data is sent back to PHP and exposed through the API

We want to go the other way round:

1. PHP has as SQLSTATE (`42S02`) and wants an error message (`Base table or view not found`)
2. SQLSTATE maps to several internal errors:

   - Error: 1051 SQLSTATE: 42S02 (ER_BAD_TABLE_ERROR) - Message: Unknown table '%s'
   - Error: 1109 SQLSTATE: 42S02 (ER_UNKNOWN_TABLE) - Message: Unknown table '%s' in %s
   - Error: 1146 SQLSTATE: 42S02 (ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE) - Message: Table '%s.%s' doesn't exist
3. PHP is confused: three messages to choose from, with `%s` symbols, none of them the wanted message.

Not to mention that that userland SQL code is allowed to generate its own SQLSTATE:

```
mysql> SIGNAL SQLSTATE 'OMG00';
ERROR 1644 (OMG00): Unhandled user-defined exception condition
```

In short, there's no way to figure out message from code for two reasons:

1. There's no one-to-one correspondence between them
2. Message appears to be a custom application text, not a built-in message you can lookup

Unfortunately, all obvious solutions are explicitly banned:

- Store the error message
- Hard-code a key/value list will all possible values

... so the only thing left is to transmit the error:

```
http://example.com/show-error?txt=Base%20table%20or%20view%20not%20found
```

... but of course you can't do that because, sooner or later, someone will send out edited links as prank:

```
http://example.com/show-error?txt=Jimmy%20is%20an%20idiot
```

So now you need to encrypt (or at least digitally sign) the message. But you wonder if you're allowed to store the encryption key in a location where both scripts can reach it...

---

*Alright, I admit I was being too melodramatic. A simple encryption/signature may possibly do the trick—I don't think that copying the secret key to both scripts goes against the rules.*

Answer (score 0):

With mySqli you can do this to handle error :

```
if (!mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName) VALUES ('Glenn')"))
  {
  echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
  }
```

With PDO try this :

```
echo "\nPDOStatement::errorInfo():\n";
$arr = $sth->errorInfo();
print_r($arr);
?>
```

Comment: I only have the sqlstate code, that's why I can't use $e->getMessage(); I have no access to the last query

Comment: Okey answer updated, if you know the db instance var you can't get errorInfo after querie was executed